# Does it make sense to convert dc.js to React?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Does dc.js implemented within React loads much more quickly in the browser than dc.js on its own? The idea is to pass the data in the props into the components and to render with dc within the relevant life cycle events such as componentDidMount. However, since dc is still responsible for the actual rendering I am not sure that React will accelerate significantly the load time in the browser. Is there anyone out there who can share the experience?

Comment: Disagree with the close votes. This is an objective question about performance. I doubt it will make any noticeable difference either way. The main bottleneck with dc.js is usually loading the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you rewrite the dc.js library and break it up into components with smart `shouldComponentUpdate` logic, it is probably faster to use dc.js outside of react.

Performance wise, if you're just wrapping the standard dc.js library in a component it will probably be **slower** than using it standalone, since the frame call tree would be slightly bigger with React. YMMV of course depending on your app.